# Default value for pointer to char in C

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Let us have the variable 
`char *s`;

I know if it's declared in global scope, its value should be 0;

If it's declared in local scope, its value is undefined (it may be 0 though).

I've got a question in test which sounds like this 'What will be the value of the pointer defined as

```
char* s
```

a) null
 b) empty string
 c) undefined

I'm really confused what answer I should choose, because if it's declared in global scope, well, the value would be null (i guess). If it's declared in local scope, undefined (though when I tried it's zero), and when I try to `cout` it, nothing is printed (no segmentation fault, why?), that means it's an empty string (or is `cout` that awesome?).

Comment: I would say - undefined (garbage) - if you compile in Debug mode, the compiler will initialize the pointer to `NULL`

Comment: To print the pointer value you need to do `cout << (void *) s`, otherwise it will try to print the null-terminated string that `s` points to, which you don't want. But I think you understand this better than whoever wrote the question.

Comment: Is this a test where you would have the ability to contest the grade?  If so, I'd choose #1, because it's much easier to argue "I assumed that was a complete piece of code, clearly the variable is not inside a function" than "I assumed the variable was inside a function even though the code does not include a function, nor am I told there is a function"

Comment: It's a daft question, since there's no semicolon there, so there could be an `= &n;` or a `= malloc(20);` after that, which would change everything. But, that aside, the value of a pointer with automatic storage duration which is not explicitly initialized is indeterminate, not undefined, so (c) is out. The *value* of a pointer can never be "empty string", so (b) is out. That leaves you with (a), which can be the only correct answer, provided you're willing to equate "null" with "null pointer".

Comment: Furthermore, since you clearly ask about the "default value for pointer to `char` in C", and then mention that you're trying to `cout` it, then evidently `s` was defined at file scope with external linkage in a different translation unit, so you can rule out automatic storage duration altogether.

Comment: Your title says "in C", but then you talk about `cout`. Unless you are trying to left-shift cout, perhaps change the title to "C++" and remove the "C" tag

Comment: Remarks: a pointer does not have a value, and null is not a defined C identifier. A pointer cannot be a string, as there are no strings in C !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The question you quoted is most likely written by a person who didn't fully understand the issue. As you correctly noted, the initial value of such pointer greatly depends on the context: where and how it is defined (local, static, aggregate member?). So, the correct answer should be an expanded one that explains these dependencies. It is weird to attempt to answer such question in a "multiple choice, only one of many" fashion.

Of course, in very general and most formally pedantic sense, the correct answer is the one that says "undefined", since in general case, not knowing where it is defined, we have to "assume the worst". But I doubt the author of the test realized that.

Comment: As a pedant, I would like to contest the claim that "undefined" is the most formally pedantic answer - but I don't have time for where that leads, so I'm not going to argue it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case the value is definitely undefined by standard. Compilers will however often default initialize it to zero in debug mode. 
When you print it out, cout doesn't do any magig, it will find a 0 and it will not print out anything.

Here are the rules for default initialization:

1. when a variable with automatic, static, or thread-local storage duration is declared with no initializer
2. when an object with dynamic storage duration is created by a new-expression without an initializer
3. when a base class or a non-static data member is not mentioned in a constructor initializer list and that constructor is called.

For example:

```
#include <string>
struct T1 {};
class T2 { 
    int mem;
 public:
    T2() {} // "mem" not in initializer list
};
int n; // This is not default-initialization, the value is zero.
int main()
{
    int n;            // non-class: the value is undeterminate
    std::string s;    // calls default ctor, the value is "" (empty string)
    std::string a[2]; // calls default ctor, creates two empty strings
//    int& r;         // error: default-initializing a reference
//    const int n;    // error: const non-class type
//    const T1 nd;    // error: const class type with implicit ctor
    T1 t1; // ok, calls implicit default ctor
    const T2 t2; // ok, calls the user-provided default ctor 
                 // t2.mem is default-initialized (to indeterminate value)
}
```

[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization)